# File upload using mysql in express js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Currently i'm doing some projects using Express 4.x and in the project seems that want to handle file upload (example: upload image on form). I am using localhost as server (mysql), searching for clue most of people using multer but i can not get. any helps, i appreciate

Answer (score 1):

[Formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) which helps you parse and get files from the POST request

Example code:

```js
const formidable = require('formidable');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// POST | /upload

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, (error, fields, files) => {
    if(error){
      res.status(500);
      console.log(error);
      res.json({
        error,
      });
      return false;
    }
    
    const image = files.image;
    console.log(image.name) // pony.png
    console.log(image.type) // image/png
    
    // Get the tmp file path
    const tmpFilePath = image.path; // /tmp/<randomstring>
    
    // Rename and relocate the file
    fs.rename(tmpFilePath, path.join(`${__dirname}/uploads/${image.name}`), error => {
      if(error){
        res.status(500);
        console.log(error);
        res.json({
          error,
        });
        return false;
      }
      res.status(201);
      res.json({
        success: true,
        upload_date: new Date(),
      });
      // Do all kinds of MySQL stuff lol
    });
  });
});
```